# How to add an image from assets folder to local HTML file and display the HTML file in Flutter WebView

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I have added an image to the assets folder but when using it in an `img` tag in the html file with "image.png" as `src` Webview in flutter is not displaying it.
I also have tried converting it to base64, which fixed the problem but i want the image in the assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code and `index.html` below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview 
In working demo you can see flutter icon `<img src="images/flutter-logo.svg" alt="flutter logo">` display correctly

Step 1: add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` 
Step 2: `pubspec.yaml` setting

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/
```

Step 3: Add files and image to `assets` folder

[image]

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

InAppLocalhostServer localhostServer = new InAppLocalhostServer();

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await localhostServer.start();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrl: "http://localhost:8080/assets/index.html",
                initialHeaders: {},
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(),
                onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {},
                onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
                onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
              ),
            ),
          )
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Flutter InAppWebView</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body class="text-center">
    <div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
        <header class="masthead mb-auto">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3 class="masthead-brand">Flutter InAppWebView</h3>
                <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="page-1.html">Page 1</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="page-2.html">Page 2</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

        <main role="main" class="inner cover">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">Inline WebView</h1>
            <img src="images/flutter-logo.svg" alt="flutter logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/flutter-logo.svg" alt="flutter logo"></a>
            <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
        </main>

        <footer class="mastfoot mt-auto">
            <div class="inner">
                <p>Cover template for <a target="_blank" href="https://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
                <p>Phone link example <a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a></p>
                <p>Email link example <a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">example@gmail.com</a></p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works only when the HTML files are also in the assets folder though. In order to load images (or other files) from assets folder when HTML is in in-memory String, src tag should be specified as: `file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/filename.extension` for Android.